# Modify bibliography style of @Online

Tags: biblatex

Can you please help me modifying my bibliography style?

I'm using biblatex with the following parameters:

- style=footnote-dw
- bibstyle=numeric
- citestyle=numeric
- url=false
- sorting=none
- backend=biber

Then I've online sources, for example:

```
@Online{online:def_commerce,
  author  = {{Oxford Dictionaries}},
  title   = {{Definition of commerce}},
  url     = {https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commerce},
  urldate = {2017-01-24},
}
```

In the bibliography, the source is printed as follows:
[image: bibliography]

I'd like to modify the output. I'd prefer it like this:

Oxford Dictionaries. *Definition of commerce*. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commerce. Accessed: 2017-01-24.

To sum it up:

- I'd like to remove the "URL:"
- After the URL should be a period.
- Instead of "(visited on xxx )" should be "Accessed: xxx."
- The date should be of format "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi samcarter, thanks for the warm welcome. Problem with a minimal working example is that I'm using a non-standard documentclass (provided by my university). However, I've found a solution for my question, and will edit the question to add the answer.

Comment: You can use a standard class to make your MWE unless you can't reproduce the problem that way. (In that case, we'd need a link for the class, as it is essential to the issue.) Please can you post your solution as an answer? The site likes to keep questions separate from answers so we can see which questions don't yet have answers. It is fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none, url=false, urldate=edtf]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@Online{online:def_commerce,
  author  = {{Oxford Dictionaries}},
  title   = {{Definition of commerce}},
  url     = {https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commerce},
  urldate = {2017-01-24},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {accessed}}


\begin{document}
\cite{online:def_commerce}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Oxford Dictionaries. Definition of commerce. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commerce. Accessed: 2017-01-24.]

Note in particular that `style=footnote-dw, bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=numeric` can be collapsed into `style=numeric`.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for pointing out style=numeric.